# Where is javac after installing new openjdk?

Tags: java, redhat, javac, rhel5

An additional jdk was installed and configured on RHEL5.

```
yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64
update-alternatives
```

It appeared to work: `java -version` points to desired 1.7.

However, `javac -version` still points to old 1.6.

`sudo update-alternatives --config javac` only lists one option.  I could not find the additional `javac`.

How do I install or configure a 1.7 `javac`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That package contains only the jre.  You need the `java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel` package.

Comment: I just install devel package as well. i.e. another alternate OR uninstall java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64 first? Preferred method?

Comment: You install the devel package as well.  Don't uninstall the jre.  The jdk requires the jre.

Answer (score 2):

On Debian, it is in the openjdk-xx-jdk-headless package.